# Angular Dragula - styling transit and mirror separately?

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula, angular-dragula

I am using nagular/dragula and trying to achieve an effect where the intended drop place is signalled by an insert line rather than an empty box. Somehow though, when I style that `.gu-transit` element like so:

```
.gu-transit {
  height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

it also affects the `.gu-mirror` element (the drag helper) - it acquires same height. Is it possible to separate those two, or is it current limitation of the module?

Comment: if I change on chrome dev-tools the `.gu-transit` class style to `background-color: purple !important` it just gives a purple background to the drop place element.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve my problem - using `height` together with `!important` still affects both classes.

Comment: Can you try using `.gu-transit { height: 0px !important; }` and `.gu-mirror {height: inherit !important}` ?

Comment: Yes, this in fact works for this particular property, but I still have problems with separating appearance one from another.

Comment: I think that's a bug, you should open a issue.